# clojureql, open-global and with-results

Tags: clojure, clojureql

Just trying to understand the purpose of clojureql's open-global and with-results. I started by reading this overview: [How does ClojureQL compare to clojure.contrib.sql?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4894161/how-does-clojureql-compare-to-clojure-contrib-sql)

I thought for some reason that open-global would replace sql/with-connection, e.g. I thought this would work:

```
(def db {...}) ; connection details omitted
(open-global db) 

(println (:name (first @(table :users)))
```

However this doesn't work. It seems I need to both do open-global and wrap the executing query in a (sql/with-connection db), which sort of surprised me (I thought open-global provided a default globally accessible connection). So since that doesn't appear to be the case I'm now left wondering exactly what it does.

Also...how does with-results differ from simply executing the query with @? Because it seems @(table :users) will leave me with a sequence that is the result of executing the query (isn't that what with-results does as well)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The difference between using `deref` (the `@` symbol) versus with-results is quite subtle. Basically both do the same thing, the only difference being at which moment the query is actually executed. Both are actually just wrappers for the `apply-on` method of the `Relation` protocol, here's the code for `with-results`:

```
(defmacro with-results
  [[results tble] & body]
  `(apply-on ~tble (fn [~results] ~@body)))
```

And for `deref`:

```
(deref [this]
  (apply-on this doall))
```

As you can see `deref` is exactly the same as:

```
(with-results [res (table :users)] (doall res))
```

If you look at `doall` documentation, you'll see that it's a function that is used to walk throught a lazy sequence to force any side-effect, the result being that the sequence will be fully evaluated, thus not being lazy anymore but residing into memory.

So to give you a more down to earth explanation, using `deref` actually execute the query at the moment it is called, while using `with-results` the query will be executed lazily, that is when the result is actually consumed.

As for `open-global`, you were right about it, it really should open a globally available connection that will be used by ClojureQL when not specifying one using `wiht-connection`. The behavior you're observing is probably a bug, so I suggest you to report it on the IRC channel or to the ClojureQL issue tracker on Github. I've not used ClojureQL in a while but looking at the code, they seems to have transitionned to using `clojure.java.jdbc` instead of `clojure.contrib.sql`, something might have gone wrong there.

Comment: a little more info, in testing I've found that if I use with-results then open-global works, but if I use deref/@ then it needs with-connection (and open-global, strangely...). I'll check on the irc, and thanks for the detailed reply!